# How to set nested path values in the tree structure?

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, sql-update

In our database, a tree structure is implemented like this:

```
name      path       pos_left     pos_right     pos_level

folder1              207          214           1
file1                208          209           2
file2                210          211           2
file3                212          213           2
```

I need to set the path's values so that rows where pos_level is 2 would read like this: folder1/file1, folder1/file2, folder1/file3.
So I need an SQL query which would take the name of the "parent" folder (but no parent_id is used in our system, only pos_left, pos_right, pos_level) concatenated with "/" and then with the entity's name.

I already have the simple stuff:

```
UPDATE table SET path = name WHERE pos_level = 1
```

And I need this:

```
UPDATE table SET path = (code I don't know) WHERE pos_level = 2
```

Thank you!

Comment: So how to build a materialised path from a nested set

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: Thanks I'll google that! mysql version: phpinfo shows Client API version 5.0.12

Comment: This would be considerably simplified in 8+

Comment: what will be the path for first row?

Comment: (You seem to be referencing a product from 15 years ago)

Comment: Rows with pos_level 1 will be identical to the names. So in this example's case it would be just "folder1" with nothing else not even the forward slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using older version of MySQL recursion is out of scope. I have used self join to get the result you want. Please use your table name instead of `treestructure` in the query:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table treestructure(name varchar(50),   path varchar(100), pos_left int,pos_right int,pos_level int)
 
 insert into treestructure(name, pos_left,pos_right ,pos_level ) values('folder1',   207,          214,           1);
 insert into treestructure(name, pos_left,pos_right ,pos_level ) values('file1',     208,          209,           2);
 insert into treestructure(name, pos_left,pos_right ,pos_level ) values('file2',     210,          211,           2);
 insert into treestructure(name, pos_left,pos_right ,pos_level ) values('file3',     212,          213,           2);
```

Update query:

```
 update treestructure t
 left join treestructure ts on ts.pos_level=t.pos_level-1 and t.pos_left between ts.pos_left and ts.pos_right  and  t.pos_right between ts.pos_left and ts.pos_right
 set t.path=(case when t.pos_level=1 then t.name else concat(ts.name,'/',t.name) end);
```

Select Query:

```
 select*from treestructure;
```

Output after update:

| name | path | pos_left | pos_right | pos_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| folder1 | folder1 | 207 | 214 | 1 |
| file1 | folder1/file1 | 208 | 209 | 2 |
| file2 | folder1/file2 | 210 | 211 | 2 |
| file3 | folder1/file3 | 212 | 213 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=20485c6455611e8c48665e3bc03f7065)*